# Android Studio: run app with release keystore to display GoogleMaps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

My app works with Android Google Maps v2.

To display a map, first I generated a map key, but it isn't working for me, because other developers should be able to work with this map too, and also I want to send the .apk to our clients to test my app.

So I decided to generate a release map key.

For this:

1) I generated a release keystore
2) Get new SH1 code
3) With Google Console generated new map key

And now when I run app from Android Studio, the map is not loading, with this error:

> Google Maps Android API: Failed to load map. Error contacting Google
>   servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to
>   network errors).

What I did wrong? When I run my app from Android Studio, is it using the release keystore?
If not, how can I tell Android studio to use the release keystore now?

Thanks...

**UPDATE 1:** If I generate an apk file and run on device, everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

I believe I read that the latest version of maps now have to have contact with the Google Play server (ie: must run on device itself now and not in an emulator). I'll be facing the same issue soon.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

I think this is what you're asking but I may have misread the question?

Comment: I did everything in that document, Map works with debug key, but its not working with release if to run app from android studio

Answer (score 0):

In the API console you may connect multiple signing keys (debug and release) with a single API key. Edit allowed apps and put each SHA-1;package pair on new line.

This way you have a single key in the AndroidManifest.xml and never have to change it.

The issue with many developers having to work on the same app is best solved by copying debug.keystore from one machine to all other. This not only helps with not having to add each keystore's SHA-1 in the API console, but also when they share devices to do test-runs, they don't get into certificate conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

For generate key of google map Live and Debug use this in command line for android studio.

Open command line on jdk bin.

**For generate debug key.**

```
c:\..\jdk\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore C:\..\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

**For generating Live Key.**

```
c:\..\jdk\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore E:\Share\Jobalerts\your.keystore
```

your.keystore == (Means your certificate)